# how can i add lambda SNS trigger with multi region

Tags: node.js, yaml, serverless-framework, amazon-sns, aws-serverless

I am trying to add multiple SNS topics of different regions to my lambda function via serverless.yml
after deployment I am seeing only one trigger.

```
functions:testLambda:
name: testLambda-${self:provider.stage}
handler: app/handlers/syncStudyData.handler
events:
  - sns: 
      arn: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxx:topicname-dev
  - sns:
      arn: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:topicname-dev
```

some times also get error

```
An error occurred: TestLambdaSnsSubscriptionxxxxdev - Invalid parameter: TopicArn (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 64caaf44-41aa-52db-9bbd-f403c591a23a; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you had different topic names, but to make it work with the same topic name different region, you will have to give "topicName" parameter which will make cloudformation create another subscription for it.

```
functions:testLambda:
name: testLambda-${self:provider.stage}
handler: app/handlers/syncStudyData.handler
events:
  - sns: 
      arn: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxx:topicname-dev
      topicName: topicname-dev-ap-southeast-2
  - sns:
      arn: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:topicname-dev
      topicName: topicname-dev-us-east-1
```

Don't worry as the lambda will subscribe to "topicname-dev", the other parameter will be used to create a unique subscription for the topics

last example here:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns#using-a-pre-existing-topic